# Types of parameters in functions that accept functions

Tags: scala, types

I am trying to learn Scala using SICP, but I am having a hard time with type definitions of functions and got stuck at [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-12.html#%25_sec_1.3.4). Here a generalized expression is build to find the square root of a number (through fixed-point search or Newton's method) where instead of:

```
def sqrt_damp(x: Double) =
  fixed_point(average_damp(y => x / y))(1)

def sqrt_newton(x: Double) =
  fixed_point(newton_method(y => square(y) - x))(1)
```

Based on the functions:

```
def square(x: Double) = x * x           
def average(x: Double, y: Double) = (x + y) / 2                                             
def abs(x: Double) = if (x < 0) -x else x 

val tolerance = 0.00001                   
def fixed_point(f: Double => Double)(first_guess: Double) = {
  def close_enough(v1: Double, v2: Double): Boolean = abs(v1 - v2) < tolerance
  def attempt(guess: Double): Double = {
    val next = f(guess)
    if (close_enough(guess, next)) next else attempt(next)
  }
  attempt(first_guess)
}

def average_damp(f: Double => Double): Double => Double =
  x => average(x, f(x))

val dx = 0.00001                                
def deriv(g: Double => Double): Double => Double =
  x => (g(x + dx) - g(x)) / dx

def newton_transform(g: Double => Double): Double => Double =
  x => x - g(x) / deriv(g)(x)               

def newton_method(g: Double => Double)(guess: Double): Double =
    fixed_point(newton_transform(g))(guess)
```

The square functions can be generalized in the form:

```
(define (fixed-point-of-transform g transform guess)
  (fixed-point (transform g) guess))
```

Which I attempted to express as follows in Scala:

```
 def fixed_point_of_transform(g: Double => Double, transform: Double => Double)(guess: Double): Double =
   fixed_point(transform(g))(guess)
```

Yet the above does not compile and generates the error

`type mismatch; found : Double => Double required: Double`

Edit, the following works:

```
def fixed_point_of_transform(g: Double => Double, transform: (Double => Double) => (Double => Double))(guess: Double): Double =
  fixed_point(transform(g))(guess)
```

So now the previous functions can be defined as:

```
def sqrt_damp(x: Double) =
    fixed_point_of_transform(y => x / y, average_damp)(1)

def sqrt_newton(x: Double) =
    fixed_point_of_transform(y => square(y) - x, newton_method)(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

`transform` takes a `Double` and returns a `Double`. You cannot apply it to `g`, because `g` is a a function `Double => Double`. You can apply it to `g(x)`, where `x: Double`. I think this is what you want: `fixed_point((x: Double) => transform(g(x)))(guess)`

Comment: I think I got it now thanks, so I should do `transform: (Double => Double) => (Double => Double)`  instead